# Unity Fog Of War Smoothness

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm making a rts game fog of war for mobile. I am using grid and map the grid cells as texture pixels to manage transparency and assign the texture to material.

My problem is the result like this.

Fog Of War Result
[image]

Any one can help me how to manage the smoothness of vision.
TY

Edit 1:
I want to make the vision smooth like this.
[image]

Comment: Please provide the picture in the post if you can or at the least describe what is happening in it that is problematic for you.

Comment: Is there an example reference what you want to achive?

Comment: @jeteon The image already shown.

Comment: @EmreE I want to make fog of war like dota 2.

Comment: Ah... sorry, I couldn't see it whilst reviewing it. It is indeed shown.

Comment: Hmm, you could try something like this. This is topdown I assume so y-axis is the distance from the ground. Add another ''pixel'' layer on top of everything. Like camera - fog layer - players - ground. Make fogging in that layer (objects or whatever you are using).  Use the same technique you are using rn, If the enemies are not in the visible distance, close their mesh renderer. Also, the fog layer will have some opacity like 0.5f. Ground will be visible a bit but enemies will not. When they are in range, enable mesh renderers of enemies. If enemies are too big this may look weird tho.

Comment: @EmreE Sorry about the image above. we can ignore about white square box (enemy tower) shown even not in range of the vision. it will be processed in server side and using sync var. My focus now just about visualization of the vision on client. The circle (vision) outline which not smooth.